# pg_dump not excluding sequences

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I'm running a pg_dump and adding five -T flags to exclude a set of tables.  In the resulting file the tables are all excluded, but only the sequence from the FIRST table specified is excluded.

I'm still seeing the `SELECT pg_catalog.setval()` calls for the other 4 tables.

How do I exclude all of them?

Answer (score 1):

Since sequence usually ends with `_id_seq`, I was able to do that for **postgres:11.2** with `--exclude-table-data` param and `'*_id_seq'` wildcard:

```
pg_dump -d foo -U postgres -f ./dump.sql --column-inserts --data-only --exclude-table-data='*_id_seq'
```

More examples [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/app-pgdump.html#PG-DUMP-EXAMPLES)